# Neo4j - Unable to rollback transaction in creating relationships with java

Tags: java, neo4j

I am trying to create some nodes in Neo4j through a Maven Java Application and create relationships between those nodes. Exactly i want to create 16807 nodes and 17210368 relationships. I read a file and get the `row` variable which has the number of nodes i must create and i also have a `list` which has 34420736 elements (=17210368*2). I want to create a relationship from node[element 0 of list] to node[element 1 from list], from node[element 2 of list] to node[element 3 from list] etc. Also the max element of list is 16807. I create an `ArrayList<Node>` as to create the nodes dynamically cause i want the programm to run with different files(and with different row values).

Here is my code:

```
    GraphDatabaseFactory dbFactory = new GraphDatabaseFactory();
    GraphDatabaseService graphDb = dbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase("C:\Users\....\default.graphdb");

    Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
    try {
        final RelationshipType type2 = DynamicRelationshipType.withName("KNOW");

        ArrayList<Node> nodelist = new ArrayList<Node>();

        for (int k = 0; k < row; k++) { //row=16807
            nodelist.add(graphDb.createNode());
            nodelist.get(k).setProperty("Name", "ListNode  " + k);
        }       

        int count=0;
        for (int j = 0; j < list.size() ; j++) { //list.size()=34420736
            nodelist.get(list.get(count)).createRelationshipTo(nodelist.get(list.get(count+1)), type2);
            count=count+2;
        }

        tx.success();
    }
    finally {
        tx.close();
    }
    graphDb.shutdown();
```

If i run the code without trying to create relationships it creates the nodes and run correctly. When i add the for loop that creates the realtionships it throws me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: Unable to rollback transaction
at org.neo4j.kernel.TopLevelTransaction.close(TopLevelTransaction.java:131)
at com.mycompany.traverse_test.traverse_main.main(traverse_main.java:138)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No RelationshipState for added relationship!
at org.neo4j.kernel.api.txstate.RelationshipChangeVisitorAdapter$1.visit(RelationshipChangeVisitorAdapter.java:132)
at org.neo4j.kernel.api.txstate.RelationshipChangeVisitorAdapter.visitAddedRelationship(RelationshipChangeVisitorAdapter.java:83)
at org.neo4j.kernel.api.txstate.RelationshipChangeVisitorAdapter.visitAdded(RelationshipChangeVisitorAdapter.java:106)
at org.neo4j.kernel.api.txstate.RelationshipChangeVisitorAdapter.visitAdded(RelationshipChangeVisitorAdapter.java:47)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.diffsets.DiffSets.accept(DiffSets.java:76)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.state.TxState.accept(TxState.java:156)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.KernelTransactionImplementation.rollback(KernelTransactionImplementation.java:542)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.KernelTransactionImplementation.close(KernelTransactionImplementation.java:404)
at org.neo4j.kernel.TopLevelTransaction.close(TopLevelTransaction.java:112)
... 1 more
```

Any ideas??

Comment: You should batch your update / data creation in 100k to 500k record sizes. Otherwise the intermediate transaction state will be larger than your heap and blow up.

Comment: try to catch exceptions and log them, then you'll see that you get an NPE or an index-out-of bound. via your finally block Neo4j tries to finish the tx, which is in a state that it can only be rolled back. Please report back the exception that's thrown.

Comment: Which Neo4j version do you use?

Comment: Also make sure in your catch blog call tx.failure()

Comment: You were rigth about the kind of error i really get. Please see the comment of the below answer.

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j is trying to roll back your transaction due to a bug in your code. The fact that it is failing to roll back may be a bug in neo4j, but that is really not your main problem.

Looking at your code, it looks like you are iterating through your `list` too many times. That is, the code in the `list` loop is using up 2 list elements at a time, so you should only be looping `list.size()/2` times.

Here is code that should fix that bug, and it also makes a few other improvements.

```
GraphDatabaseFactory dbFactory = new GraphDatabaseFactory();
GraphDatabaseService graphDb = dbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase("C:\Users\....\default.graphdb");

Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
try {
    final RelationshipType type2 = DynamicRelationshipType.withName("KNOW");

    ArrayList<Node> nodelist = new ArrayList<Node>();

    for (int k = 0; k < row; k++) { //row=16807
        Node node = graphDb.createNode();
        node.setProperty("Name", "ListNode  " + k);
        nodelist.add(node);
    }       

    for (int j = 0; j < list.size() ; j += 2) { //list.size()=34420736
        nodelist.get(list.get(j)).createRelationshipTo(
            nodelist.get(list.get(j+1)), type2);
    }

    tx.success();
} catch(Throwable e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    // You may want to re-throw the exception, rather than just eating it here...
} finally {
    tx.close();
}
graphDb.shutdown();
```

[EDITED]

However, the above code can still run out of memory, since it is trying to create so many resources (16K nodes and 17M relationships) in a single transaction.

The following example code does the work in multiple transactions (one for creating the nodes and node list, and multiple transactions for the relationships).

`NUM_RELS_PER_CHUNK` specifies the maximum number of relationships to be created in each transaction. The `createRelEndpointList()` method must be modified to fill in the list of relationship endpoint (node) indices (each index is the 0-origin position of a node in `nodeList`).

```
public class MyCode {

    private static final int NODE_COUNT = 16807;
    private static final int NUM_RELS_PER_CHUNK = 1000000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doIt();
    }

    private static void doIt() {
        GraphDatabaseFactory dbFactory = new GraphDatabaseFactory();
        GraphDatabaseService graphDb = dbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(new File("C:\\Users\\....\\default.graphdb"));

        try {
            RelationshipType type = DynamicRelationshipType.withName("KNOW");

            List<Node> nodeList = createNodes(graphDb, NODE_COUNT);
            List<Integer> list = createRelEndpointList();

            final int numRels = list.size() / 2;
            final int numChunks = (numRels + NUM_RELS_PER_CHUNK - 1)/NUM_RELS_PER_CHUNK;

            int startRelIndex = 0, endRelIndexPlus1;
            for (int i = numChunks; --i >= 0 && startRelIndex < numRels; ) {
                endRelIndexPlus1 = (i > 0) ? startRelIndex + NUM_RELS_PER_CHUNK : numRels;
                createRelationships(graphDb, nodeList, list, startRelIndex, endRelIndexPlus1, type);
                startRelIndex = endRelIndexPlus1;
            }
        } finally {
            graphDb.shutdown();
        }
    }

    private static List<Node> createNodes(GraphDatabaseService graphDb, int rowCount) {
        ArrayList<Node> nodeList = new ArrayList<Node>(rowCount);
        Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
        try {
            final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("ListNode  ");
            final int initLength = sb.length();
            for (int k = 0; k < rowCount; k++) {
                Node node = graphDb.createNode();
                sb.setLength(initLength);
                sb.append(k);
                node.setProperty("Name", sb.toString());
                nodeList.add(node);
            }
            tx.success();
            System.out.println("Created nodes.");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            tx.failure();
            return null;
        } finally {
            tx.close();
        }
        return nodeList;
    }

    private static List<Integer> createRelEndpointList() {
        final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        // Fill
        //   list
        //     ...

        return list;
    }

    private static void createRelationships(GraphDatabaseService graphDb, List<Node> nodeList, List<Integer> list, int startRelIndex, int endRelIndexPlus1, RelationshipType type) {
        Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
        try {
            final int endPlus2 = endRelIndexPlus1 * 2;
            for (int j = startRelIndex * 2; j < endPlus2; ) {
                Node from = nodeList.get(list.get(j++));
                Node to =   nodeList.get(list.get(j++));
                from.createRelationshipTo(to, type);
            }
            tx.success();
            System.out.println("Created rels. Start: " + startRelIndex + ", count: " + (endRelIndexPlus1 - startRelIndex));
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            tx.failure();
            // You may want to re-throw the exception, rather than just eating it here...
        } finally {
            tx.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Good point but the error remains. I didnt understand why Neo4j trying to rollback my transaction. Where is the bug to my code?? It is a very simple code with the exception that has a huge number of relationships that must create.

Comment: If there is an exception thrown in the `try` block, the `finally` block will call `tx.close()` (and `tx.success()` won't be called). Closing a [Transaction](http://neo4j.com/api_docs/2.0.3/org/neo4j/graphdb/Transaction.html) without indicating it was successful will cause a roll back. I've modified my answer to print a stack trace if there is an exception.

Comment: I add `e.printStackTrace()` and also call `tx.failure()` in catch blog as Michael Hunger advice and it prints me `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. Do anyone know why i get this error?